# How can I register my app to the "service" command?

Tags: services, redhat-enterprise-linux, packages

On RedHat EL 6, many services can be started and stopped on the command line:

```
service some_service start
```

and

```
service some_service stop
```

I have packaged a Node.JS server application in an RPM. How can I register my app to `service`, for easy `start` and `stop`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to write an init script for your service and install it in the `/etc/rc.d/init.d` directory.

I found [one example script on Github](https://gist.github.com/thehunmonkgroup/2031806); it may be of use to you after some minor customization. And an Internet search will probably turn up other such scripts.

Comment: That link is dead now. Care to provide the source directly?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [RPM guidelines for Fedora](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/index.html) (Fedora is upstream for RHEL, so they should be applicable with some futz for newer versions). You will still have to write the init script, that is more of a black art. Filch the `/etc/init.d` file for something similar as a starting point, compare to others.

Be advised that Fedora switched to [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd), and it is a given that RHEL 7 will use that also. That means that startup is radically changed (and writing of startup files much simplified). Perhaps you should install latest Fedora and start experimenting.